# Automatically create subfolder and filter for sender's email domain

Tags: thunderbird, autohotkey

A very common use case I've noticed in my and others' email workflow is to get email from a new contact that I need to create a filter for. This entails:

- creating a subfolder for that domain
- creating a filter by clicking on the sender's email address and selecting "Create a filter from"
- setting the filter to match email where From/To/CC/BCC contains the domain
- and finally selecting the folder to move it to

I've searched unsuccessfully for a Thunderbird addon or a way to script this easily within Thunderbird, so that by selecting an email and clicking on a button or context menu, it performs the above steps for that email unless the folder/filter already exists.

I am aware of but not familiar with [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), for example it could look at msgFilterRules.dat for existing filters, and then add to those. However, how would it check for existing (IMAP) folders and then create one? After an initial look, I couldn't find any mention of being able to do this with AHK, and would still prefer to have a self-contained Thunderbird solution.

Does anyone know of any easy way to do this within Thunderbird, or an addon for it?

Comment: What type of server is thunderbird talking to - is it an IMAP server?  Do you have access to it (you could possibly do this filtering server-side if so).

Comment: IMAP yes. Interesting, I didn't know you could do that. I'm looking into it right now.